# MYSQL, How to design a "add0remove" users setting table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am currently designing a settings table for a new app. There is a setting "add0remove," which means if users get added or excluded from a specific "targeting." Next, I created the table "user/list_add0remove" to save all added or removed users/user lists per setting.

I am especially worried about the "user/list_add0remove" table: Imagine there are 3,000 settings that add each on average of 100 different users. The "user/list_add0remove" table will get huge over time as a consequence, and the queries may take some time. (The app use-case makes it impossible to save "certain targetings" and reuse them again over time)

How to resolve that? And in general, optimize the below table schema?

[image: Visual Schema]

I can choose in "Admin-Newsletter-Settings" if I want to add or remove users to the current newsletter targeting.

"add0remove" means
0=remove or
1=add.

For example, I target with my newsletter all users from Italy but want to remove certain users from Italy or add additional users outside Italy.

Comment: I don't understand the relationships between settings, lists, and users.

Comment: Thanks for reading my question!
I can choose in "Admin-Newsletter-Settings" if I want to add or remove users to the current newsletter targeting.

"add0remove" means 0=remove or 1=add.

For example, I target with my newsletter all users from Italy but want to remove certain users from Italy or add additional users outside Italy.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you can only add lists to a setting, but you can add additional users or remove some users.  Can you remove entire lists from a setting?  How would that work if a particular user was on the list added to a setting and the list removed from a setting?

Comment: "add0remove tinyint (1) NULL" DEFINES if the chosen users or lists get ADDED on top or REMOVED from the current targeting.
Imagine a form that has a dropdown input field with the options "remove" and "add" and another input field in which you can select users and/or lists.

Comment: Again, can you remove entire lists from a setting?  if you can, how would it work if the same unique user was on an added list and at the same time on a removed list?

Comment: "A setting" aggregates several targeting options. 
For example, you can target: "Country, Gender & Age."

Next to the general targeting options, you can choose between two additional targeting options:

- ADD USERS
or
- REMOVE USERS

You can never choose "ADD" and "REMOVE" at the same time.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Imagine your targeting includes "Country=Italy." But you want to remove certain Italian users. In that case, you will choose the additional targeting "Remove Users."

Comment: For "many-to-many" mapping tables, use the tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, this is what I understand.

1. A setting can have zero to N users.
2. A user can have zero to N settings.
3. A list can have zero to N users.
4. A user can belong on zero to N lists.
5. A list is a convenient way to group multiple users with a shared interest.
6. A list can be added to a setting.  A list can never be removed from a setting.

So, the first thing I would do is associate settings with users.

```
Setting
-------
Setting ID
Setting Name
...
Setting Create Timestamp
Setting Update Timestamp


User
----
User ID
User Name
User Email
User Gender
User Birthdate
User Create Timestamp
User Update Timestamp


SettingUser
-----------
Setting ID
User ID
SettingUser Create Timestamp
SettingUser Update Timestamp
```

The SettingUser association table has a unique index on Setting ID, User ID.  You can also have a unique index on User ID, Setting ID.  The second index allows you to get a list of settings that a user is associated with.

There's no need to have an add or delete flag in the SettingUser association table.  If the row exists, the user is associated with the setting.  If the row doesn't exist, the user is not associated with the setting.

If you need to keep track of the deleted users, then add a boolean flag to the SettingUser association table to mark which rows have been "deleted".

Your database does not have to look like your GUI.  Your database has to work with your GUI.  Your application code translates the GUI inputs into data that can be stored in a database.  Your application code translates the data from the database into outputs displayed on the GUI.

A list has a similar relationship to a user.

```
List
----
List ID
List Name
List Create Timestamp
List Update Timestamp


ListUser
--------
List ID
User ID
ListUser Create Timestamp
ListUser Update Timestamp
```

The reasoning for the ListUser association table is similar to the reasoning for the SettingUser association table, so I'm not going to repeat it.

There's no connection between a List and a Setting in the database.  It's up to your application code to retrieve the users associated with a List and associate them with the appropriate setting row.